# How to save a params object in jsonb column in active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a model with a jsonb column called `answers`.
And I am trying to save a params object which is as follows

```
params[:questions] = {\"ad6d1d19-f95b-228c-8a19-49150ad15f23\"=\u003e\"pavan\", \"90783719-9cd6-23de-f3fb-9bc80e7a72a0\"=\u003e\"eeeeeee\"}
```

by doing

```
Model.create(answers: params[:questions])
```

But I am getting the following error.

```
Expected #7855876856 but got "ad6d1d19-f95b-228c-8a19-49150ad15f23"
```

I am stuck here could someone please help here?

Comment: Seems to me there's a syntax error in your `{\"ad6d1d19-f95b-228c-8a19-49150ad15f23\"=\u003e\"pavan\", \"90783719-9cd6-23de-f3fb-9bc80e7a72a0\"=\u003e\"eeeeeee\"}`, but I assumed you just have a typo, because the error you're getting is different.

Comment: no the params I am getting is right. The error is because of some `string` conversion issue. But not able to figure out what

Comment: you're assigning a `Hash` to `params[:question]`, right? Then you should use `:` or `=>` and not `=`. I tried it in my console, I didn't get a SyntaxError, but the expression is deemed incomplete. i.e. try it in your `irb`: `hash =  {\"ad6d1d19-f95b-228c-8a19-49150ad15f23\"=\u003e\"pavan\", \"90783719-9cd6-23de-f3fb-9bc80e7a72a0\"=\u003e\"eeeeeee\"}` `puts hash`